# Send mail in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to send mail in C# windows application.But I don't want to use SMTP Server. Is there any other way to send mail Other than SMTP.

If anyone knows please share.

Comment: You could use Outlook if it's installed - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911230/sending-email-through-outlook-2010-via-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to send email via a Gmail account, you can use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/), which has C# libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install your own SMTP Server, you could also rely on DNS to lookup the emailaddress of your recipient, and talk to their SMTP Server.
More information can be found [here](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=5), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776987/sending-email-with-c-sharp-without-smtp-server), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637866/sending-mail-without-installing-an-smtp-server) and [here](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/direct_send.html)